Is it possible to pick out an element in a JSON response structure based on a name in letters
I am making an HTTP API call using Pytest and want to obtain a value given a name in letters.
The response looks like this:
  [
   {
    "hpsId": 10032,
    "powerPlant": {
      "name": "Svartisen",
      "id": 67302,
      "regionId": 40,
      "priceArea": 4,
      "timeSeries": null,
      "units": [
        {
          "generatorName": "Svartisen G1",
          "componentId": 673021,
          "timeSeries": null
        },
        {
          "generatorName": "Svartisen G2",
          "componentId": 673022,
          "timeSeries": null
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "hpsId": 10037,
    "powerPlant": {
      "name": "Stølsdal",
      "id": 16605,
      "regionId": 20,
      "priceArea": 2,
      "timeSeries": null,
      "units": [
        {
          "generatorName": "Stølsdal G1",
          "componentId": 166051,
          "timeSeries": null
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]

I want ot get the attribute value (166051) for componentId for generatorName Stølsdal G1 in the above response and save the value.
But how can I search for this given I only know the name of the generator before the request is being made?
I was thinking like this:
componentId= response.json()[what to put here?]["hpsId"]["componentId"] 


Your requirement is unclear. What result do you want?

you need to loop through the list and look for it.

@gre_gor Please don't link to javascript questions from Python questions.

When you convert the JSON data to something that you can use in Python, you will have a list of dictionaries.
There's no shortcut solution. You just have to navigate through the structure.
For example:
import json

data = '''[
   {
    "hpsId": 10032,
    "powerPlant": {
      "name": "Svartisen",
      "id": 67302,
      "regionId": 40,
      "priceArea": 4,
      "timeSeries": null,
      "units": [
        {
          "generatorName": "Svartisen G1",
          "componentId": 673021,
          "timeSeries": null
        },
        {
          "generatorName": "Svartisen G2",
          "componentId": 673022,
          "timeSeries": null
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "hpsId": 10037,
    "powerPlant": {
      "name": "Stølsdal",
      "id": 16605,
      "regionId": 20,
      "priceArea": 2,
      "timeSeries": null,
      "units": [
        {
          "generatorName": "Stølsdal G1",
          "componentId": 166051,
          "timeSeries": null
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]'''

def getComponentId(generatorName, jdata):
    for d in jdata:
        for unit in d["powerPlant"]["units"]:
            if unit["generatorName"] == generatorName:
                return unit["componentId"]

print(getComponentId("Stølsdal G1", json.loads(data)))

Output:
166051

Note:
Returns None if the given search criterion cannot be found

from json import loads

def get_component_id(data, name):
  return next(
    unit["componentId"] 
      for hps in data
      for unit in hps["powerPlant"]["units"]
        if unit["generatorName"] == name
  )

data = loads(response.json())

print(get_component_id(data, "Stølsdal G1"))


Might be worth explaining what happens if the specified name can't be found
